# How to open files automatically when starting emacs?

Tags: emacs

A newbie question and probably very *bingable* (had to use that word once :-)), but as I gather thats both ok for SO : How can you get files to open automatically when starting emacs?

I guess it sth. like executing the `find file` command in your `.emacs` but the exact notation isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
C-h b
```

This opens the help showing the correspondence between key-bindings and elisp functions.
Look for

```
C-x C-f
```

in it (you can do it by typing `C-s C - x space C - f`), you find `find-file`. Now, do

```
C-h f find-file
```

and it tells you, among other things, the syntax :

```
(find-file FILENAME &optional WILDCARDS)
```

So just try

```
(find-file "/path/to/your/file")
```

in your .emacs

Comment: tx, all very usefull, I know it's basic, but haven't found the time to work my way in yet.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there.

Comment: The exhibition of process here is worth at least as much as the answer itself. Nice.

Comment: 5 years later now :) but just wanted to say this is an awesome answer! Really  helpful, instead of just stating the answer this gives the knowledge to be able to figure out things ourself for future problems.

Comment: This is the exact type of answer more users should give. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 23):

Are you thinking of having it re-open files you've looked at before?  The [desktop](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeskTop) package remembers files and re-opens them when you restart.  Depending on your emacs version, you enable by simply adding this to your .emacs (for 22.1+ versions):

```
 (desktop-save-mode 1)
```

And after that, it's pretty much automatic.  Whatever files you had open before will be re-opened (provided you start from the same directory, b/c that's where the desktop configuration file is saved) - unless you add a change that forces a [single desktop for all sessions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeskTop#toc3).

There are bunches of variants of that functionality, which are listed [in the session management page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement).

Comment: Great answer! When I close emacs, it always asks if it needs to save desktop! how to bypass this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling it from the terminal , can't you just go

> emacs FileName

Answer (score 2):

You could desktop-save which basically restores the last session you were working with. When you restart emacs, it looks for a saved session in your folder and loads your files. 
See [link text](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html)