# How to open an org-mode file automatically in Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

[How to open files automatically when starting emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999708/how-to-open-files-automatically-when-starting-emacs) does not work either under Windows or under Linux.

After adding the `find-file` command I received a message

[image: recover]

so I disabled the `auto-save`, but the file does not load anyway.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs/org-8.0.3")
(setq auto-save-default nil)
(find-file "/home/uwe/Dropbox/orgmode.org")
```

Comment: Are you sure there is something in the file? This should work regardless of autosave and loadpath.

Comment: It was loaded indeed, switching the buffer helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to set the `initial-buffer-choice` variable so that it switches to your org file after running your init.el.

```
(setq 
 org-default-notes-file "/home/uwe/Dropbox/orgmode.org"
 initial-buffer-choice  org-default-notes-file)
```

Answer (score 2):

The message you see proves that the file is indeed loaded just fine.  All it tells you is that there's some auto-save file left over, indicating that some edits were not saved last time.  You can ignore the message (which is not an error message), or you can use `M-x recover-this-file RET` to recover the unsaved changes from the auto-save file.

I strongly recommend you don't disable auto-saving.

IOW what you think doesn't work (automatically loading orgmode.org) actually does work.  The only thing that doesn't work the way you want is that this file is not *displayed* and instead the `*scratch*` buffer is displayed.  The reason for this depends on how you started Emacs.  And the fix for it depends on all the different ways you might start Emacs (e.g. if you only ever start Emacs in the exact same way, it's easier).

Answer (score 1):

Don't disable the auto-save, it could save ours files.

Anyway, delete `#orgmode.org`, if the diff between the two file don't interest you.